# JPA with PostgreSQL - simple relationship

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

Tables:

- pattient ( id, name, id_status, ...) -> FK to pattient_status
- pattient_status (id, description) -> target table

All I need is to obtain pattient_status.description inside my pattient.class, because my GET method needs this information on the JSON return.

Code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="cad_paciente")
public class Paciente {

... (other columns)

@OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(insertable=false, updatable=false, name = "id_status_paciente", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private StatusPaciente status;

public String getStatusPaciente(){
        return status.getStatus();
    }

----
@Entity
@Table(name="cad_status_paciente")
public class StatusPaciente {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="ds_status")
    @Size(max=50)
    private String status;
```

This lists my information correctly, but on POST method, JPA saves correctly but returns the message:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: (was java.lang.NullPointerException); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: com.spin.spincare.model.Paciente["statusPaciente"])]
```

What should I do?

Comment: Where does that happen?  Are you returning the object in the controller?  Is that where the jackson error happens?

Comment: The error happens on the return of POST method (PUT method works fine), tested in Postman.. the result JSON doesnt return on the response body but the record is persisted (saved) on my database correctly.. I think that something is missing on the annotations or relationships..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an issue with your getter:

```
public String getStatusPaciente() {
    return status.getStatus();
}
```

In your POST call status is null, so when Jackson uses this getter to generate the JSON it gets a null pointer exception.  Update it to something like:

```
public String getStatusPaciente() {
    if (status == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return status.getStatus();
}
```

Comment: That's what I was missing! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `@MapsId`. This will make ids of entities match. Read more [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).

```
@Entity
@Table(name="cad_status_paciente")
public class StatusPaciente {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @MapsId
    @OneToOne
    private Paciente paciente;


    @Column(name="ds_status")
    @Size(max=50)
    private String status;
}
```